# How to pass a list of files to <exec>?

Tags: ant

This is a part of my ant script:

```
<target>
  <exec executable="find" outputproperty="found">
    <arg value="src/main/java"/>
    <arg line="-name '*.java'"/>
  </exec>
  <exec executable="xgettext">
    <arg value="-k_"/>
    <arg line="-o gettext.pot"/>
    <arg line="${found}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Doesn't work because `xgettext` receives a **quoted** list of files and treats this list as a single file name. How to solve it?

Comment: <arg line="`find src/main/java -name '*.java'`"/> instead of `<arg line=${found}"/>` doesn't help?

Comment: No, doesn't help. In this case `xgettext` will receive a quoted `"find src/ma..."` string. Not a back-quoted shell command.

Comment: Consider using apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288010/apache-ant-difference-exec-vs-apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to separate out each file to a separate `arg` for that to work.

You can supply a list-of-files file to process to 'xgettext' using the [`--files-from`](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html) option.
How about something like this: write the 'find' output to a file, then reload into 'xgettext':

```
<target>
  <exec executable="find" outputproperty="found">
    <arg value="src/main/java"/>
    <arg line="-name '*.java'"/>
  </exec>
  <echo file="xgettext.files" message="${found}" />
  <exec executable="xgettext">
    <arg value="-k_"/>
    <arg value="-o" />
    <arg value="gettext.pot"/>
    <arg value="--files-from=xgettext.files"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Alternatively, here's a variation that assumes you have the Bourne Shell `sh` - if you have something else you can probably adapt.  This pipes the 'find' output directly to 'xgettext':

```
<exec executable="sh">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value="find src/main/java -name '*.java' | xgettext -k_ -o gettext.pot -f -"/>
</exec>
```