# Apache Ant difference - exec vs apply

Tags: ant

Can anyone tell me the difference between `<exec>` and `<apply>` in Apache Ant?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The main difference is that [`apply`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) works for a resource collection - fileset, dirset and the like - so you can, for example, run a script once for each member of a fileset.  [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) doesn't operate on a fileset; each instance of the task only runs a single external program.  Otherwise the tasks are quite similar.

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow. For programming it, it works way better than plain googling. =)